# How to check given date is which friday of the month?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have dates like below:

```
2017-08-04
2017-08-18
2017-08-11
2017-08-25
```

I want to know that this dates are which Friday of that particular month. **If the month containing five Friday's like below:**

```
2017-06-02 // It should return 1
2017-06-09 // It should return 2
2017-06-16 // It should return 3
2017-06-23 // It should return 4
2017-06-30 // It should return 5
```

**Same like above:**

```
2017-08-04 // It should return 1
2017-08-18 // It should return 3
2017-08-11 // It should return 2
2017-08-25 // It should return 5
```

**Edit 1:** I tried it like below:

```
datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).strftime("%V")
```

But It is returning the value from the start of the year.

```
d=datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28)
(d.day-1)//7+1
```

It is not counting Friday. It is just counting 7 days from the start of the month.

Can we do it in python?

Comment: what did you done so far for this?

Comment: Please tell us, at which part of the code you are stuck and share with us your own ideas on the problems and possible solutions.

Comment: Probably [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) could help

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
import datetime

def x(y,m,d):
  d = d=datetime.datetime(y,m,d)
  firstday = d.replace(day=1)
  print(d.isocalendar()[1] - firstday.isocalendar()[1] + 1)


x(2017,8,18)

x(2017,8,25)
```

Comment: @ShoaibZafar- Thanks for you help. It's good solution and quit simple.

Comment: @ShoaibZafar- It fails for some date like x(2000,01,07).

Comment: interesting ... well use `print(int(d.strftime("%W")) - int(firstday.strftime("%W")) + 1)` ... also use the correct case `x(2000,1,7)`